# Jquery Remove Based on two attributes ( dynamic substitution )

Tags: jquery

I have a DIV with below attributes

```
<div car_id='1' car_type='4'><br>GM<a href="#" id="yt0"><img title="Delete" src="/cardelete/images/delete.png" alt="Delete" /></a></div>
```

Basically it has two attributes

```
car_id='1' car_type='4'
```

On my Ajax success function I want to remove the above . I am able to alert **obj.car_id**
and **obj.car_type**

But that remove part is not working . Could some one provide the correct syntax for it ?

```
"success"=>'js:function(data){                                                             
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    alert(obj.car_id);
    alert(obj.car_type);
   $("div[car_id=obj.car_id][car_type=obj.car_type)".remove();
```

}',

Thank You

Regards

Kiran

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you’re doing this:

```
$("div[car_id=obj.car_id][car_type=obj.car_type)".remove();
```

As far as JavaScript is concerned, that’s a single selector string. Since you want parts of the selector to be filled with the values of `obj.car_id` and `obj.car_type`, you’ll need to use string concatenation, like this:

```
function(data){                                                             
  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
  alert(obj.car_id);
  alert(obj.car_type);
  $('div[car_id="' + obj.car_id + '"][car_type="' + obj.car_type + '"]').remove();
}
```

Comment: Thank You . Initially I tried appending , But got into some other errors . Your solution helped me to find the correct one . Since I am already in the single quotes ( the success function ) adding '\' before "single quote" helped me .  Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div[car_id="'+obj.car_id+'"][car_type="'+obj.car_type+'")'.remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused by the syntax here (what language is this in? why is the JS function stored as a string?), but there are a couple of obvious problems. The first is that you aren't inserting the variables into the string – you're treating their names as string literals. The second is that you don't properly close the selector, as would be evident if you used code highlighting, which is impossible because the function is stored as a string.

```
function(data){                                                             
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    alert(obj.car_id);
    alert(obj.car_type);
    $("div[car_id='" + obj.car_id + "'][car_type='" + obj.car_type + "'])".remove(); 
}
```

Note also that I have inserted quotes into the [attribute equals selector `\[name="value"\]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector), as technically is required.

Comment: @lonesomeday FYI, whether it’s technically required to add the quotes depends on the attribute value (which is unknown in this case, so it’s definitely a good idea to add the quotes). See [_Unquoted attribute values in selectors (CSS and JavaScript)_](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-attribute-values#css).

Comment: @MathiasBynens Technically it is required by jQuery, even if it's passed to `qSA`. See the API page I link to.

Comment: @lonesomeday Where does it say so on that page? Try `jQuery('[class=question-page]')` in your console on this page. It works. Same for `qSA`. That’s because [it’s a valid unquoted attribute value in CSS](http://mothereff.in/unquoted-attributes#question-page).

Comment: @MathiasBynens "**value** An attribute value. Quotes are mandatory." I know it *works* without the quote, because the selector is passed to `qSA` and Sizzle can cope with it anyway, but technically it is mandatory.

Comment: @lonesomeday The quotes are recommended because that way it always works, no matter the value, and you don’t really have to think about it. But it’s perfectly fine to omit them if http://mothereff.in/unquoted-attributes tells you it’s okay.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your string to use the objects properties (car_id and car_type) and not just the strings "obj.car_id" and "obj.car_type". You have also incorrectly closed the attribute selector (missing a final ']') and your jQuery selector.

A correct solution would be:

```
$("div[car_id='" + obj.car_id + "'][car_type='" + obj.car_type + "']").remove();
```